# Unit testing click event in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to add unit tests to my Angular 2 app. In one of my components, there is a button with a `(click)` handler. When the user clicks the button a function is called which is defined in the `.ts` class file. That function prints a message in the console.log window saying that the button has been pressed. My current testing code tests for printing of the `console.log` message:

```
describe('Component: ComponentToBeTested', () => {
    var component: ComponentToBeTested;

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = new ComponentToBeTested();
        spyOn(console, 'log');
    });

    it('should call onEditButtonClick() and print console.log', () => {
        component.onEditButtonClick();
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Edit button has been clicked!);
    });
});
```

However, this only tests the controller class, not the HTML. I don't just want to test that the logging happens when `onEditButtonClick` is called; I also want to test that `onEditButtonClick` is called when the user clicks the edit button defined in the component's HTML file. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to test for a console log?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

> My objective is to check if the 'onEditButtonClick' is getting invoked when the user clicks the edit button and not checking just the console.log being printed.

You will need to first set up the test using the Angular `TestBed`. This way you can actually grab the button and click it. What you will do is configure a module, just like you would an `@NgModule`, just for the testing environment

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let component: TestComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ],
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [  ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));
});
```

Then you need to spy on the `onEditButtonClick` method, click the button, and check that the method was called

```
it('should', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'onEditButtonClick');

  let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  button.click();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.onEditButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
}));
```

Here we need to run an `async` test as the button click contains asynchronous event handling, and need to wait for the event to process by calling `fixture.whenStable()`

#### Update

It is now preferred to use `fakeAsync/tick` combo as opposed to the `async/whenStable` combo. The latter should be used if there is an XHR call made, as `fakeAsync` does not support it. So instead of the above code, refactored, it would look like

```
it('should', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'onEditButtonClick');

  let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  button.click();
  tick();
  expect(component.onEditButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

}));
```

Don't forget to import `fakeAsync` and `tick`.

#### See also:

- [Testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing)
- [What is the difference between fakeAsync and async in Angular testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42971537/2587435)

Comment: what if we have more than one button in the html file? Doing something like: fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');

Comment: looks for 'button' in the html file, but what we have more than two one button? How should I reference the second button occurrence for testing?

Comment: I got the solution! button = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button');
button1 = button[0];

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed that you omitted the import for IonicModule.forRoot, though. For me the test fails once I add that. Isn't it required for other testing scenarios?

Comment: I just spent a day trying to figure out why this wasn't working for me only to realize I was calling click on my component's element not the div inside it I'm actually listening for clicks on.

Comment: what is the difference between button.triggerEventHandler('click', null ) and button.click90?

Comment: Perfect solution. :)

Comment: This Worked for me, id of button prefixing as button#, let btn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("button#button_id");

Comment: How will you write test cases for a row click in a table?

Comment: Whatever I write inside whenStable it passes wrong assert as well, even if you write expect(false).toBeTruthy(); it will pass this assert.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre do you have the callback wrapped in async? Anyway, it is advises to use fakeAsync now instead of async. Use async only when there is an XHR call.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yes i wrote that in async but till it was passing wrong assert. I ended using fakeAsync and tick

Comment: Thanks, btw I am getting this error "Expected spy onSubmit to have been called.", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Another way to select the button : const button = debugElement.query(By.css('#buttonId')).nativeElement;

Answer (score 58):

Events can be tested using the `async`/`fakeAsync` functions provided by `'@angular/core/testing'`, since any event in the browser is asynchronous and pushed to the event loop/queue.

Below is a very basic example to test the click event using `fakeAsync`.

The `fakeAsync` function enables a linear coding style by running the test body in a special `fakeAsync` test zone.

Here I am testing a method that is invoked by the click event.

```
it('should', fakeAsync( () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(componentInstance, 'method name'); //method attached to the click.
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    btn.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    tick(); // simulates the passage of time until all pending asynchronous activities finish
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(componentInstance.methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Below is what [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) have to say:

> The principle advantage of fakeAsync over async is that the test appears to be synchronous. There is no `then(...)` to disrupt the visible flow of control. The promise-returning `fixture.whenStable` is gone, replaced by `tick()`
>
> **There *are* limitations. For example, you cannot make an XHR call from within a `fakeAsync`**

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer this solution or the accepted solution?  As an angular noob, I have no idea which is "better"

Comment: @AdamHughes fakeAsync is more easier to read and understand according to angular documentation. But you can choose whatever suits you best. There is nothing like accepted solution when using aync or fakeAsync.

Comment: I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972411/2587435) about the comparison between the use of `async` vs. `fakeAsync`. Even though in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093298/2587435) I used `async`, in general, my preference would be to use `fakeAsync`.

Comment: You should only have `tick()`s if your code is calling `setTimeout`, I don't think a tick is needed? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574080/227299

Comment: I prefer this solution as it uses debugElement (Which is an environment agnostic selector).

Comment: [tick](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) is explicitly used for simulating the passage of time. In most cases, `detctChanges` is enough.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using **Angular 6**. I followed Mav55's answer and it worked. However I wanted to make sure if `fixture.detectChanges();` was really necessary so I removed it and it still worked. Then I removed `tick();` to see if it worked and it did. Finally I removed the test from the `fakeAsync()` wrap, and surprise, it worked.

So I ended up with this:

```js
it('should call onClick method', () => {
  const onClickMock = spyOn(component, 'onClick');
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
  expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And it worked just fine.

Comment: my general strategy has been to always invoke `fixture.detectChanges()` in order to trigger angular's lifecycle events. it may have been the case that your component doesn't have an `ngOnInit` or that it wasn't necessary for the test to pass.

Comment: @SnailCoil or he could use automatic change detection (https://angular.io/guide/testing#automatic-change-detection)

Comment: Some dom events are synchronous. For example the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is documented to be synchronous. If you what are experiencing with the button click event is true, then that means that the button click event is also synchronous. But there are a lot of Dom events that are _asynchronous_, in which case you _would_ need to use `async` or `fakeAsync`. To be safe, I don't see anything wrong with assuming that all events are asynchronous and just use `async` or `fakeAsync` (it's your preference).

Comment: In case you are not running in a complete browser, using By.css instead of querySelector is better. (src https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400566/angular-4-unit-test-de-queryby-css-versus-native-web-api-of-de-nativeele).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Seems like a bad idea to litter your code with `tick()`s because something may potentially be async? You should know what is and isn't async. Triggering mouse/keyboard/input events is always synchronous.

Comment: the link to automatic change detection Maksymilian posted has moved to https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#automatic-change-detection

Answer (score 3):

to check button call event first we need to spy on method which will be called after button click
so our first line will be spyOn
spy methode take two arguments 
1) component name
2) method to be spy i.e: 'onSubmit' remember not use '()' only name required
then we need to make object of button to be clicked
now we have to trigger the event handler on which we will add click event
then we expect our code to call the submit method once

```
it('should call onSubmit method',() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onSubmit');
    let submitButton: DebugElement = 
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type=submit]'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    submitButton.triggerEventHandler('click',null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. I am using Angular 7. I think the right approach is: 

```it('should call onSubmit method',() => {
    let mock = spyOn(component, 'onSubmit');
    let submitButton: DebugElement = 
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type=submit]'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    submitButton.triggerEventHandler('click',null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (detailed explanation below), and I solved it (in `jasmine-core: 2.52`) by using the `tick` function with the same (or greater) amount of milliseconds as in original `setTimeout` call.

For example, if I had a `setTimeout(() => {...}, 2500);` (so it will trigger after 2500 ms), I would call `tick(2500)`, and **that would solve the problem.**

What I had in my component, as a reaction on a *Delete* button click:

```
delete() {
    this.myService.delete(this.id)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.message = 'Successfully deleted! Redirecting...';
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          }, 2500); // I wait for 2.5 seconds before redirect
        });
  }
```

Her is my **working** test:

```
it('should delete the entity', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.id = 1; // preparations..
    component.getEntity(); // this one loads up the entity to my component
    tick(); // make sure that everything that is async is resolved/completed
    expect(myService.getMyThing).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    // more expects here..
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const deleteButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-danger')).nativeElement;
    deleteButton.click(); // I've clicked the button, and now the delete function is called...

    tick(2501); // timeout for redirect is 2500 ms :)  <-- solution

    expect(myService.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    // more expects here..
  }));
```

P.S. Great explanation on `fakeAsync` and general asyncs in testing can be found here: [**a video on Testing strategies with Angular 2 - Julie Ralph, starting from 8:10, lasting 4 minutes :)**](https://youtu.be/C0F2E-PRm44?t=8m10s)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a css class to query by, you can use a function match on an attribute that suites your situation.

```
it('should call onClick from button element', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'onClick').and.callFake(() => null);

  fixture.detectChanges();

  const button = fixture.debugElement.query(
    (val) => val.attributes['id'] === 'button-1'
  );

  expect(button).toBeTruthy();

  trashCanButton.children[0].triggerEventHandler('click', {});

  tick(1000);

  expect(component.onClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```