# Subscribe for component using mock service is not being executed during test

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have a component that uses a service and, as you can imagine, this service is implemented in another class. For the test of this component, I already mocked the service. Basically, this is my component file where I subscribe to the service:

```
this.tokenManagerService.retrieveToken().subscribe(token => {
  const tokenRetrieved = JSON.parse(token);
  console.log(tokenRetrieved);
  if (tokenRetrieved.error) {
    this.error = tokenRetrieved.error;
}
```

And this is my test configuration for the component where I mock the service:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  tokenManagerServiceMock = new TokenManagerServiceMock();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ AuthenticationComponent ],
    imports: [ FormsModule, HttpModule,RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]) ],
    providers: [
      { provide: TokenManagerService, useValue: tokenManagerServiceMock }
    ]
  });
  TestBed.overrideComponent(AuthenticationComponent, {
  set: {
    providers: [
      { provide: TokenManagerService, useValue: tokenManagerServiceMock }
    ]
  }
});
```

And this is my test:

```
it('should detect white field message', () => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    inputEmail.nativeElement.value = faker.internet.email();
    inputEmail.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    inputPassword.nativeElement.value = faker.internet.password();
    inputPassword.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    loginButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});
```

When the `loginButton.click()` is executed, it should trigger the enter in the `onSubmit`, which actually is happening. But why the `subscribe` method is not being executed?

O**BS:** This is the method for the mock service where the component is subscribing:

```
public retrieveToken(): Observable<string> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

**EDIT:** @picciano suggested that this topic was already solved in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093013/unit-testing-click-event-in-angular). But actually, not. What I pretty sure that the code is calling the methods inside `onSubmit`, just not calls the method that using `subscribe`, while in the other topic, he wants to know if the method is called or not. Also, the method that is being subscribed is executing, I already printed inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing click event in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093013/unit-testing-click-event-in-angular)

Comment: @ScottMcMaster I edit the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In general, if you're using whenStable() you should be wrapping with async(): https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_code_async_code_and_code_whenstable_code

Comment: I see this got downvoted but FWIW you should still be using async().