# Unable to get select button click in unit testing using Jasmine and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi here i am using Angular and trying to create a unit test for the Reactive form but unable to succeed

what i required : How to execute button click after the form is filled both with false and truthy values using jasmine in angular.

what i did : I created a logic but it is not working

```
 it('Form check is valid or not if no values entered', () => {

    expect(component.userCreationForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('Form check is valid or not when values entered', () => {

    component.userCreationForm.controls['firstname'].setValue('luther');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['lastname'].setValue('adams');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['email'].setValue('test@gmail.com');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['password'].setValue('123456');
    expect(component.userCreationForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Form Submitted should check from is submitted', () => {
    // check form is invalid
    expect(component.userCreationForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type=submit]'));
    // Check button is disabled
    expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
    component.userCreationForm.controls['firstname'].setValue('luther');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['lastname'].setValue('adams');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['email'].setValue('test@gmail.com');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['password'].setValue('testpassword');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // check button is enabled
    expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();

    component.onUserCreation();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let success = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#success-msg')).nativeElement;
    expect(success.textContent).toBe('Bubba');

 });
```

html logic

```
<div class="inv-buttons">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="userCreationForm.invalid" type="submit">Create User</button>
        </div>
```

Below is my stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-q9wxvq

Comment: Well if I understand it correctly, you're not calling click anywhere. You're just checking enabled/disabled state of the button. Try `btn.click()` after check, if it's enabled.

Comment: @dallows can u point  me to that ?

Comment: Add `btn.click()` just under `expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();`

Comment: getting error as Property 'click' does not exist on type 'DebugElement'

Comment: try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093298/3359635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where ever you want to click that btn you have created. Use it like below :-

```
 btn.nativeElement.click();
```

I changed your test case below :-

```
it('Form Submitted should check from is submitted',async () => {
    // check form is invalid
    expect(component.userCreationForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type=submit]'));
    // Check button is disabled
    expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
    component.userCreationForm.controls['firstname'].setValue('luther');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['lastname'].setValue('adams');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['email'].setValue('test@gmail.com');
    component.userCreationForm.controls['password'].setValue('testpassword');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // check button is enabled
    expect(btn.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    console.clear();
    btn.nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //component.onUserCreation();
    //fixture.detectChanges();

    //let success = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#success-msg')).nativeElement;
    //expect(success.textContent).toBe('Bubba');

 });
```