# How to write unit test for a function in button click in angular

Tags: angular

**I write a code for unit testing but it isn't worked. I wanna know how to use it and I am new to unit testing**

**COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<button class="set-button" (click)="clickFunction()"> SAVE</button>
```

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
clickFunction(){
console.log('WORKED');
}
```

**COMPONENT.SPECS.TS**

```
    it('function on button click ', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'clickFunction');
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('set-button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().Then(() =>{
    expect(component.clickFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  });
```

**I want to know what have i done wrong here.Thanks in advance**

Comment: Does this help? [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093013/unit-testing-click-event-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you never actually perform any `click` on your button:

```
  it('should click button', () => {
    const clickFunctionSpy = spyOn(component, 'clickFunction');
    const btn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(
      'set-button'
    ) as HTMLButtonElement;
    btn.click();
    expect(testClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

If the test still fail, it might be that your `querySelector` is wrong (do you have an element with the tag `<set-button>`?)

Comment: iam getting an `function not implemented` error and what is **testClickSpy** means

Comment: So in short, you create a `spy` whenever you want to test whether a `function` has been called or not. I would highly recommend that you take a look at some tutorial on Angular Testing (there's a really good Udemy course on that too). Unfortunately it is not simple and without understanding the basic, you can't really proceed any further.